# Sum of one row for each data in other row are not grouped with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a SQL that shows different results from what I want in a jasper report

I have 2 same rows: OFFICER and DOC_TYP in a 3 tables. I want to do a sum of all doc_typ for each officer and group them by officer name. This is my code

But in the end my result is that OFFICER names are not sorted and I found the same name lot of times.

```
SELECT DAT, VAL, TYP, OFFICER, som
  FROM ( ------------------1-visa
       SELECT VR.DOC_DAT  DAT,
              VR.DOC_VAL  VAL,
              VR.DOC_TYP  TYP,
              VR.OFFICER  OFFICER,
              COUNT(*) as som
         FROM ASYEVR_VRQ_TAB vr
        WHERE vr.doc_dat > = to_date($P{p1},'dd/mm/yyyy')
          AND vr.doc_dat < = to_date($P{p2},'dd/mm/yyyy')
          AND (   ($P{p5} is null) 
               OR (vr.officer = $P{p5})
              ) 
        GROUP BY vr.officer, vr.doc_typ, vr.doc_dat, vr.doc_val
---------------------2-work permit 
       UNION
       SELECT GT.DOC_DAT  DAT,
              GT.DOC_VAL  VAL,
              GT.DOC_TYP  TYP,
              GT.OFFICER  OFFICER,
              COUNT(*) as som
         FROM ASYEVR_ASYWPE_TAB gt 
        WHERE gt.doc_dat > = to_date($P{p1},'dd/mm/yyyy')
          AND gt.doc_dat < = to_date($P{p2},'dd/mm/yyyy') 
          AND (   ($P{p5} is null) 
               OR (gt.officer = $P{p5})
              ) 
        GROUP BY gt.officer, gt.doc_typ, gt.doc_dat, gt.doc_val
---------------------3-residency 
       UNION
       SELECT RS.DOC_DAT  DAT,
              RS.DOC_VAL  VAL,
              RS.DOC_TYP  TYP,
              RS.OFFICER  OFFICER,
              COUNT(*) as som
         FROM ASYEVR_RESIDENCY_TAB rs
        WHERE rs.doc_dat > = to_date($P{p1},'dd/mm/yyyy')
          AND rs.doc_dat < = to_date($P{p2},'dd/mm/yyyy')
          AND (   ($P{p5} is null) 
               OR (rs.officer = $P{p5})
              ) 
        GROUP BY rs.officer, rs.doc_typ, rs.doc_dat, rs.doc_val
        )

    <field name="OFFICER" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TYP" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="som" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
```

I am seeing it like that

```
officer         DOC_TYP           SUM
Mike           visa                7
mike           visa                8
mike           work permit         2
laura          work permit         1
laura          work permit         2
laura          work permit         3
```

But what I need is seeing like that

```
mike           visa                   7
               work permit            5

laura          visa                   9 
               work permit            2
```

Comment: Your query doesn't have an `order by`.  Why would you expect your results to be ordered?

Comment: lol i forgot about the order by lol thank you for help ;)

Comment: So are you really asking they they aren't sorted, or why you see the same officer/doc type combination multiple times even if they are sorted?

Comment: i have many 2 problems they are sorted now but i want to see for each officer the sum of each doc_typ for example we have officers mark laura michael and mariah

i am seeing it like that

officer         DOC_TYP           SUM

Comment: i am seeing it like that

officer         DOC_TYP           SUM
Mike           visa                      7
mike           visa                      8
mike
laura         work permit           1
laura          work permit           2
laura          work permit           3

but what i want is seeing like that

mike           visa                   7
                   work permit      5

laura          visa                    9
                  work permit        2

Comment: so i want for each officer the sum for each TYP he maid and don't want the name of zach officer in each row and i don't know i have the visa repeated a lot of tome with different sum values in each officer...is this SQL wrong???

Comment: i edited the original post to see how i see it and how i want to see it

Comment: Since you are using Jasper you can do it there, Just creating groups and variables to sum the values.

Comment: but i want to do it with only sql ;) because we test in toad too...so my boss want it full sql without lot of jasper tricks...the only one thing we can do only with jasper is the not repeated name and didn't find how to do it with jasper that's why i asked here :)